# In jQuery was a document fragment, string, or object passed to constructor?

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to know how I can tell in my plugin whether the user passed a document fragment or DOM string - or if they passed an actual object. If they are passing in a DOM string or document fragment I need to `.appendTo('body')`

```
$('p.my_plugin').myPlugin();
// or
$(object).myPlugin();
// vs
$('<p>My string</p>').myPlugin();
```

The basic plugin shell

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                console.log(this);
                ....
```

Comment: `this.is('*')` seems to work, though I didn't test it much.  I'm also not sure if `.is('*')` is even valid.

Comment: And when you use the term *document fragment*, are you actually referring to a type 11 *documentFragment*? Or are you using that term to describe something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this too much, and I'm not sure if it's valid, but `this.is('*')` seems to work.

```
$('p.my_plugin').is('*');  // true

$(object).is('*'); // false

$('<p>My string</p>').is('*'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just check if the element has a parent:

```
if(!this.parent().length) {
    this.appendTo($('body'));
}
```

Comment: `$({a:12}).parent()` and `$('<p>My string</p>').parent()` both return `[]`.

Comment: i would think attempting to call .parent() method on a string would cause an undefined reference error.

Comment: Not calling parent on a string just returns and empty jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof this[0] === 'object') {
    // they passed an object
} else {
    // they passed something else (a string, for example)
}
```

Comment: Inside a jQuery plugin, `this` is the jQuery object.  It's unknown what was passed to `$()` inside the plugin.

Comment: in that case, you would want this[0] or this.get(0)

Comment: `this[0]` would never *not* be an object (unless an array was passed to `$()` eg. `$(['a', 'b', 'c'])`).